# Unexpected behaviour of ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, built-in-symbols

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1.2 && 0 < z, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 
  1.2}, {z, -1.2, 1.2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[#^2 + #2^2 + #3^2 < 1, Blue, 
     Opacity[.2, Red]] &), Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Actually this code want to render the range `x^2 + y^2 + z^2` from 0 to 1 with blue and the outer sphere with `Opacity[.2, Red]` .But why do I get this? Is it a bug of `ColorFunction`?

## Update(by Simon Woods's comment)

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1.2 && 0 < z, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 
  1.2}, {z, -1.2, 1.2}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[#^2 + #2^2 + #3^2 < 1, Blue, 
     Opacity[.1, Red]] &), Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 Boxed -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image]

The remaining questions is why we cannot see the inside blue through the transparent red?

Comment: It's not a bug - the parameters fed to `ColorFunction` are scaled to run from 0 to 1 unless you specify `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`

Comment: You are not making it clear what you find wrong with the result you are getting. It is obvious to you, of course, but not to me. Please give details about what is bother you. Is the coarseness of the boundary mesh? The ugly colors? Or something else?

Comment: @SimonWoods Wow,I cannot realize this option.You comment solve this question almost,but why we cannot see the inside blue through the red?

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry I made some typo,but I have updated for that.

Comment: Of course you can see the blue through the translucent red. But with your color function, the only part of hemisphere that gets colored blue is the base.

Comment: `RegionPlot3D` only draws the *surface* of the region - there is no inner hemisphere to paint blue. `ColorFunction` can only color the polygons that are there, it cannot create additional inner surfaces. You probably need to create the red and blue hemispheres with separate plots and combine them using `Show`.

Comment: @SimonWoods I have used that.Bad effect,which will produce some extra texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegionPlot3D` only draws the surface of the region - there is no inner hemisphere to paint blue. ColorFunction can only color the polygons that are there, it cannot create additional interior surfaces. You could instead create the red and blue hemispheres with separate plots and combine them using Show:

```
rp[r_, col_] := RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < r && 0 < z,
  {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, {z, -1.2, 1.2},
  PlotStyle -> col,
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotPoints -> 50]

Show[rp[1.2, Opacity[.2, Red]], rp[1.0, Blue]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get a better understanding  of what happens when you try to use a color function to divide a surface into opaque and translucent parts, you might want to experiment with a color function that divides your hemisphere into sectors.

```
RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1. && 0 < z, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, {z, -.2, 1.2},
  PlotPoints -> 150,
  MaxRecursion -> 7,
  BoxRatios -> Automatic,
  Boxed -> False,
  Mesh -> None,
  ColorFunction -> 
    (If[0. < ArcTan[Abs[#1], Abs[#2]] < N[π/4], Lighter[Blue], Opacity[.2, Yellow]] &),
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]